# Getting poor Half-Life: Alyx performance with a 1080 Ti -- what can I do to improve performance?

Tags: graphics-card, system-requirements, steam-vr, half-life-alyx

I have a GeForce 1080 Ti GTX graphics card. I play Half-Life: Alyx with it using High Quality preset settings. I've heard from numerous people that the game runs really well on it, but I can't seem to make it happen. Some people even reported that the game runs great with a regular 1070 as well.

I have Valve Index set to target 90FPS (I tried 120FPS but that was unplayable). When playing HLA, fpsVR keeps reporting that most of the time the game is running at 45FPS raw, while the rest is provided by 25-50% reprojection rates.

The game looks fine if you're not moving too much or are in a simple room, but the reprojection rate becomes very apparent when you begin playing "normally". It manifests itself as extreme ghosting in the world. It is not unplayable, but very very ugly.

Medium settings are better in terms of not reprojecting as much, but as mentioned, I keep hearing about folks running High Settings just fine with the 1080 Ti.

What would you consider the performance of a stock 1080 Ti be with Half-Life: Alyx, if the GPU was the bottleneck, and the game was set on High Quality settings preset? Could one expect to reach 90FPS with minimal reprojection (0-15%)?

My system is Windows 10 Pro with Intel i7-8700K, 16GB DDR4 RAM, and the game is running on a ~500MB/s SSD storage. The GPU is 1080 Ti as mentioned.

Comment: I haven't had issues with a regular 1080, but that was playing on a first generation HTC Vive, which has almost half the resolution of the Index.